# Improve Tessract detection on grayscale image

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have an issue with text recognition on same files with low contrast. I'm using PYTESSERACT and some files, like this, return me absolutely nothing : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbgQm.png

I use the LineBoxBuilder from PyTesseract. Before that, I convert the PDF into JPG :

```
def save_img_with_wand(self, pdfName, output):
    with Img(filename=pdfName, resolution=300) as pic:
        pic.compression_quality = 100
        pic.background_color    = Color("white")
        pic.alpha_channel       = 'remove'
        pic.save(filename=output)
```

Linebox builder :

```
def line_box_builder(self, img):
    try:
        return self.tool.image_to_string(
            img,
            lang=self.lang,
            builder=pyocr.builders.LineBoxBuilder()
        )

    except pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError as t:
        self.Log.error('Tesseract ERROR : ' + str(t))
```

If nothing was found, I use OpenCV to improve detection :

```
@staticmethod
def improve_image_detection(img):
    src     = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    dst     = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(src, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11, 2)
    cv2.imwrite(img, dst)
```

I tried multiple OpenCV solutions, but in all the cases, I wasn't able to read the text on a shitty background like in the image above

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `erode()` + `dilate()` should take care of the small dots, apply until happy =)

Comment: Using this two openCV function, I have this result : http://i.imgur.com/jngmtx9.png 
Not really nice :/

Comment: the result you've got looks quite strange, maybe this might help: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html

Comment: This is the article I use to test erosion and dilation :/